# Zoho Rest Invoice API Return 400 Error, Java HttpClient

Tags: java, spring-boot, invoice, zoho

I want to integrate Zoho Invoice API in my Spring Application. I have integrated `AuthToken` part successfully. Now I am working with Create contact API. But API returns an error 400.

I am using the following code:

```
public String processZohoRequest(String apiUrl,Map<String, String> params,String method, String auth) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
    URL url = new URL(apiUrl);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod(method);

    if(!AppUtility.isEmpty(auth)) {
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", auth);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        con.setRequestProperty("X-com-zoho-invoice-organizationid", testZohoOrgId);
    }

    if(!AppUtility.isEmpty(params)) {
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        out.writeBytes(ParameterStringBuilder.getParamsString(params));
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        content.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    con.disconnect();

    return content.toString();
}
```

I use sam method for obtaining access token which is working but when use it for create contact it returns error. Can anyone tell how I can fix this ?

```
`API-URL`: https://invoice.zoho.com/api/v3/contacts
```

`json String` : "{\"contact_name\":\"Jay Panjwanai\",\"company_name\":\"Ozone\",\"billing_address\":{\"attention\":\"Jay \",\"address\":\"${address}\",\"city\":\"INDORE\",\"country\":\"India\",\"phone\":9xxxxxxxxx},\"shipping_address\":{\"attention\":\"Jay\",\"address\":\"${address}\",\"city\":\"INDORE\",\"country\":\"India\",\"phone\":9xxxxxxxxx}}"

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after discussing with their support team I got the answer. Just remove the following line:

```
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
```

This was creating a problem.

Regards